# Pull Replication for Remote Repository from instance artifactory 6 to instance artifactory 7 don´t

Tags: artifactory

I'm new artifactory user and I want to make a replication of a remote repository called "roti_conan"

from my artifactory instance server 6.22.5 to instance artifactory 7.23.5 on "rotifiles_conan".

To do that I used the pull Replication for remote repos ,but when I changed and put the new URL

(https://artifactory.roti.local/artifactory/rotifiles_conan/) inside edit of "roti_conan" to get a connection bethween the remote repositories , I get this failure :
`Error testing pull replication config: Unable to identify target URL as an Artifactory instance: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found .`

What can I do to fixe that ? It is possible for me to use the "event-based pull Replication" to resolve that ? If yes, how can I use it ?

Thank you so much

Romeo

Comment: I forgot to mention that , I tried  to ignore this failure and finish to edit  ,but the replication don´t properly work , inside of "rotifiles_conan" it missed some files and metadata from the original Repo "roti_conan" . Why this happened ?

Answer (score 0):

I understood you are configuring the [smart remote repository](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Smart+Remote+Repositories#SmartRemoteRepositories-Configuration) for Conan and then enable the pull replication. The 404 is expected because the URL should include "api/conan" context in it. Change the URL to below and test the connection,

> https://artifactory.roti.local/artifactory/api/conan/rotifiles_conan

Comment: Sorry, I'm giving a sign now. Yes I tried and it works fine, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: No problem :) Good to know it resolved now